# CURSOR LOOP within TRANSACTION

Tags: mysql, loops, transactions, cursor

I can't even get this basic CURSOR LOOP to run in my TRANSACTION.

Please help.  Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ClearItems(IN itemName CHAR)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE bID INT(255);
    DECLARE bIDs CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE column1 = itemName AND column2 = 'b' ORDER BY column3 DESC, date ASC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    START TRANSACTION;
        OPEN bIDs;
        clear_loop: LOOP
        FETCH bIDs INTO bID;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE clear_loop;
            END IF;
        INSERT INTO table2 (column1) SELECT bID;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE bIDs;
    COMMIT; 
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Check the syntax errors.

Comment: None reported.  Everything goes through.  Do you get them when you try it?

Comment: This line will throw some errors  -'WHERE 1column1 = itemName AND 1column2 = 'b' ORDER BY 1column3 DESC'. The field `1column1` and other ones have to be quoted or named correctly.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are columns quoted?  itemName is the IN procedure value.  Can that not be done, searching columns in a WHERE with the IN value?  Or does the syntax have to change when doing that?  Many thanks.

Comment: I just tried it without the LOOP, and it INSERTs an empty value.  Do you have to use a special syntax for CURSORs when using WHEREs?

Comment: 1column1 is a column.  itemName is from the "CREATE PROCEDURE ClearItems(IN itemName CHAR)" line.

Comment: Yes. This code can be executed. I thought MySQL will throw an error on columns named like `1column...`, because it starts with a number. But I'd suggest you to rename these fields or quote them with backtick '`'.

Comment: I think I just wasted some of your time.  Those aren't the real column names.  I'll rename them.  I've stripped out the LOOP, and the INSERT now fires, but it the value for ID seems to be NULL.  Any thoughts?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the problem - rename declared ID variable. Field names and variables should not be the same.

---

Also, if you want to populate another table, try to use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement. It will help you to avoid using cursors. For example -

```
INSERT INTO table2(`2column1`)
  SELECT id
    FROM table1
    WHERE `1column1` = itemName AND `1column2` = 'b'
    ORDER BY `1column3` DESC, date ASC;
```

Comment: Sorry again.  That's also not the real name of the declared variable.  I'll change it to a little closer to what it is.

Comment: I have a whole set of code that I put inside the transaction, so I'm not trying to do an INSERT.  I'm just trying to strip it down to the bare bones, so I can figure out what's wrong.  I think it's the way I'm DECLARing or OPENing or FETCHing the CURSOR, but I have no idea.

Comment: It's still INSERTing 0 (NULL, I'm guessing).  The LOOP wouldn't even fire when I tried it.  There must be something wrong with my syntax somewhere.

Comment: I commented out the "item = itemName" part, and the cursor worked.  How can I use my IN variable?  Thanks again.

Comment: The 'itemName' argument is used correctly. Check if it inserts anything, write something like this - INSERT INTO table2 (column1) VALUES(1). Also check if SELECT query returns data set, just execute that SELECT query without cursor.

Comment: Try to [debug](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) the procedure, it will help to find the error quickly; you can use free trial version.